# Android : customized button not showing in avd

Tags: android, xml

Hello I tried to customize a button in my app.So in res/drawable-xdpi in a new xml file i put the following code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#ef4444" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#992f2f" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#ef4444"
          android:endColor="#992f2f"
          android:angle="270" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#992f2f" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

The thing is that in graphical layout the button is customized as it is supposed to be,but when i run the app on AVD the customizations are not displayed and it just shows the default buttons.Am I missing something here?

ALSO:

full xml layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#151515" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/gram"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"


         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/schedule"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="@string/announcement"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste full xml layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `red_button.xml` file should go in `res/drawable` folder. If it doesn't exist in your project's hierarchy, add a new folder by right-clicking on `res` directory and name it `drawable`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think you are, are your sure your AVD is "HDPI" ? If not, that's your problem !